# Getting dump from Crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

We've been using `breakpad`+`hockeyapp` for reporting crashes in our android app (most of which is in C++). With that I can download memory dump (which `breakpad` created) later from HockeyApp and inspect it using `gdb` to see some local variables and registers. Also I can feed other android libraries into `gdb` to symbolicate missing parts of stack for which libraries are device-specific.

Can I get such dump from Crashlytics?